# $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {x}(a^{1/x}-1)$, such that $a > 1$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, infinity

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {x}(a^{1/x}-1)$, such that $a > 1$

**My Approach:**

Since $x$ approaches infinity I presume we have to 'get rid' of the $x$ on the outside because the root $-1$ will be more than 0 but I have no idea how to reduce the $x$ so please help me out!

Comment: Hint $(e^x-1)/x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hôpital?

Comment: Replace $x$ by$\frac{1}{h}$. Then use property $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ when $a>0$.

Comment: We are not allowed to use L'Hôpital's Rule

Comment: Yep, @ShubhamKumar, that works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty} x(a^{1/x}-1)$$
let $x=1/t$, then
$$L=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{a^t-1}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1+t\ln a+(t\ln a)^2/2+...-1}{t} =\ln a.$$

Comment: More simply, the limit corresponds to the definition of the derivative  of the function $a^t$ at $t=0$.

Comment: yes, this is another way (L'Hospital).

Comment: No, it's not L'Hospital – only the very definition of the derivative

Comment: It is the same thing, again, which also is right.

Answer (score 1):

Recall :  $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{e^y-1}{y}=1;$

Set $y:=1/x,$ and consider $y \rightarrow 0^+$.

$\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}\log a (\dfrac{e^{y\log a-1}}{y\log a}) = \log a. $

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to a slightly more general limit

$ \displaystyle L(m, n) = \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{m} ( a^{\frac{1}{x^{n}}} -1) \tag*{} $

Where $ a>1 $ and $(m, n) $ are natural numbers.

$ \displaystyle L(m, n) =  \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{m} ( e^{ \frac{\ln(a)}{x^n}} -1) =  \lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{m-rn}}{r!}(\ln(a))^{r} \tag*{} $

Where we have used the series expansion of the exponential function in the step above. It should be now straight forward to observe that the given limit is equal to $0$ whenever $ m<n$, Equal to $\ln(a) $ when $m=n$ and the limit diverges to infinity whenever $m>n$.